# How to pass an array/data object to a SQL Server stored procedure from mulesoft

Tags: arrays, sql-server, stored-procedures, mule, data-objects

Currently we are inserting a single record into the database at a time. Now I need to pass 1000 records at a time to a stored procedure in input parameter as array/data object and perform bulk insert.

I have looked up the options for passing the records as json and xml. Is there any other way to do it from mulesoft?

Comment: Google `Table-Type Parameters` for SQL Server Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Its best practice to send multiple records in a SOAP Envelope and make your SQL Procedure to accept SOAP payload. If the procedure is not accepting 1000 records then you can use the-

**BATCH PROCESSOR FLOW** in Mulesoft, if you have Full subscription of Mule then you can use this feature, Batch processing is specifically designed for processing large number of records See the below link for your reference-

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/batch-processing